# ffmpeg not receive udp stream multicast on CentOS 6.9

Tags: ffmpeg, centos6

I install ffmpeg packge on CentOS 6.9 but CentOS not receive udo multicast stream. I added input udp on iptables but it still not receive udp multicast

Comment: Show your ffmpeg command

Comment: Do simple multicast test seem to work?